# RxSwift .map Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

Tags: swift, xcode, rx-swift

How can I solve this problem? At the `map` function, it says Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions.

```
let manuallyShowFerryInBoundPopup = Observable.merge([
            NotificationCenter.default.rx
                .notification(NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive)
                .map { _ in () },
            viewDidAppear
            ])
            .flatMap { VADApi.FerryDestination.list(skip: 0, take: 1, token: VADDataManager.getUserToken()!) }
            .map { $0.first }
            .filter {
                $0 != nil
                && "\(String(($0?.ferry?.id)!)),\(String(($0?.id)!))" != VADDataManager.shownFerryInBoundTrace
            }
            .map { ( ($0?.ferry?.id)!, ($0?.id)! ) } // Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler can not understand the result type due to complex code. Specifying result types in your closures will help. For example change your last map to something like this (real code depends on actual types, I will just make an assumption):

```
.map { data -> (String, String) in ((data?.ferry?.id)!, (data?.id)!) }
```

UPDATE:
If this does not help you may want to add more type specifying to your code:

```
let manuallyShowFerryInBoundPopup: Observable<(String, String)> = Observable.merge([
            NotificationCenter.default.rx
                .notification(NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive)
                .map { _ in () },
            viewDidAppear
            ])
            .flatMap { _ -> Observable<[YourEntitiy]> in VADApi.FerryDestination.list(skip: 0, take: 1, token: VADDataManager.getUserToken()!) }
            .map { entities -> YourEntitiy in entities.first }
            .filter { entity -> Bool in
                let entityTrace = "\(String((entity?.ferry?.id)!)),\(String((entity?.id)!))"
                return entity != nil && entityTrace != VADDataManager.shownFerryInBoundTrace
            }
            .map { entity -> (String, String) in ((entity?.ferry?.id)!, (entity?.id)!) }
```

Comment: This couldn't work, I am still having the same error.

Answer (score 0):

If you work hard to make your code human-readable, it will be a breeze to make it compiler-readable. As it stands, I can't look at most of those transformations and figure out the type. If it's hard for me as a human to infer types, then the compiler, which already really struggles and bogs down with type inference, will have an even harder time.

As mentioned in another comment, being explicit with type in each of the transformation blocks will help.

Also, when applying several complex RxSwift expressions in a row like this, I think that it's a good idea (while not as cool/exciting) to assign the output of each transformation to a new, clearly named variable.

Remember: You're not writing machine code or assembly. You're writing in a high-level language. And the #1 reason for doing that is so that the code can be read by other human beings. If your code works to violate that, you should reevaluate the way it's written.